# How to pass value from partial view to shared view _Layout.cshtml in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, viewbag

There is a controller which catches an exception. I would like to pass the error message to a generic javascript in _Layout.cshtml so as to apply to all pages. It is totally find if the value is passed from normal view to _Layout.cshtml by, e.g. @ViewBag = "error message"; in the view or ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "error message"; in the controller, but it is not working in partial view.

What should I do in order to pass the string message from partial view to _Layout.cshtml??

Comment: On what event you want to pass the value ? on the page load ?

Comment: ViewBag should be accessible in the layout file, can you please post some code to show what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do.  But you could put a script block in your partial view that runs a global javascript function once it renders, possibly containing a message or other data.

for instance in _Layout you have:

```
<script>
    function ShowError(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
</script>
```

and then in your partial you have:

```
<script>
 // check for existence of error and if so
 ShowError(ErrorMessage);
</script>
```

Comment: Mostly `Partial View` don't use `_Layout file`. So this solution is not efficient one...

Comment: @mmushtaq but it is specifically in the question.

Comment: @mmushtaq Is there any other solution other than using _Layout file if I want to globally apply the alert function to all partial views?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from partial view to its layout during the same request, you can do so via the `ViewBag` object:

partial view file

```
@{
ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "error message";
}
```

_layout file

```
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
{
    <script>
    alert(@ViewBag.ErrorMessage);
    </script>
}
```

If you want to catch an exception in controller's action and then pass error message on redirect, you can do so using `TempData`:

controller

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(){
...
try{
  ....
}catch(Exception e){
  TempData["errorMessage"] = e.Message;
  return RedirectToAction("MaybeSomeOtherAction");
}
...
}
```

_layout file for "MaybeSomeOtherAction"

```
@if (TempData["errorMessage"] != null)
{
    <script>
    alert(@TempData["errorMessage"]);
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a common Property for Errors;

```
 public static class Common
    {
        public static bool ERROR {get;set;}
    }
```

If exception thrown or to show an Error Message, set this Property true;

```
try
{
   //Any Code
}
catch(Exception)
{
   Common.ERROR = true;
   return PartialView("_PartialView");

}
```

At Your _Layou file, Views or _Partial View, you can check this property at `Document.Ready` and if it is true then you can show an Error alert.

```
$(function(){               
         if(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@HelloWorldMvcApp.Common.ERROR)))
         {
                alert("error message");
                    return;
        }
})
```

***<kbd>[Demo if this property is True](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xpq0UL)</kbd>***

***<kbd>[Demo if it is False or its value is not set to true](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KkkL0h)</kbd>***